# Get rid of + image sprite for job alert - gives impression of expansion when not

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Please get rid of the plus symbol shown below:

[image]

It gives the user the impression that this collapses for some reason.  Aside from that the green colors used for the sprite vs the text `Email me...` do not match giving this an <strike>atrocious</strike> odd look!

Also why do we show this link when no search is performed?  I think it should be:

`style=display:none;`

Unless someone has actually entered a keyword or a location - hardly anyone I know wants an alert for ALL jobs in ALL locations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the note! Icon and font color have been updated - you'll see the fix in the next prod build.

As for hiding the action on searches with no criteria - good point. Alert creation for "all new jobs" may be an edge case, so we'll need to dig into our metrics to verify. We'll consider this for future iterations.

Comment: I still don't understand the green coloring of this or why there is a silly icon next to it.  Why isn't there an icon for the link next to it?  Why not just remove the icon?  What is the green signifying in this case?  Why can the jobs site not maintain some sort of state of consistency.  I see so much randomness in all of jobs I seriously despise the entire design of the site - no offense.  Right next to that same link is another link allowing you to `Manage Your Alerts` which that one is in blue.  And why in God's name is there a huge area for tips on how to use job search?